# Yandex DataLens - Cannot union tables with similar columns

Tags: yandex

I try to union tables with same columns (each table is for a single day) so that I could create charts based on information from all the tables but when I try to create a dataset, it only JOINs tables which ends in a table with 'horizontal' addition (doubled columns) while I need a 'vertical' addition.
Example:

```
table_1

|  date     |   event    |
|------------------------|
|2023-11-01 |installation|
|2023-11-01 |  deletion  |
|2023-11-01 |  purchase  |

table_2
|  date     |   event    |
|------------------------|
|2023-11-02 |installation|
|2023-11-02 |  deletion  |
|2023-11-02 |  purchase  |
|2023-11-02 |ad_watching |
```

What I want to have:

```
table_union

|  date     |   event    |
|------------------------|
|2023-11-01 |installation|
|2023-11-01 |  deletion  |
|2023-11-01 |  purchase  |
|2023-11-02 |installation|
|2023-11-02 |  deletion  |
|2023-11-02 |  purchase  |
|2023-11-02 |ad_watching |
```

What I have in reality:

```
________________________________________________________
|  date     |   event    |  date(1)    |   event(1)    |
--------------------------------------------------------
```

Any ideas?

I tried Google and SQL in DataLens but it was not helpful

Comment: How are you doing union, are you using a query? If so, can readers see it?